# How deterministic nature of our world emerges?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, probability, determinism

Quantum mechanics shows that nature is non-deterministic. But the world we see around us seems deterministic. Take for an example: harmonic oscillator when $n$ becomes very large the probability distribution mimics that of classical mechanics. So my question is how can we extract the information of $"Seemingness"$ of determinism of the world around us from Schrodinger Eq. i.e. around what scale the apparent determinism become noticeable or is it example specific. Also How the quantum world will look like if we can observe it our scale say for example that $\hbar$=$1$ $Js?$

Comment: Your last sentence is really an entirely separate question

Comment: You might be interested in reading Richard Feynman's very short book QED, where (among other things) he explains how the classical view of reflection of light off a mirror emerges from a Quantum Mechanical calculation.